# ui:repeat doesn't work with f:selectItem

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

i am using icefaces select on menu to select a user from list of users
and i want to repeat the selectItem for each user
here's what i tried:

```
<ice:selectOneMenu id="users">
    <ui:repeat value="#{user.getUserList()}" var="user">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{user.name}" itemValue="#{user.id}"/>
    </ui:repeat>               
</ice:selectOneMenu>
```

**UserBean:**

```
@Component("user")
@Scope("view")
Public class UserBean{

Public List<User> getUserList() throws Exception {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

}
```

**NOTE:** UserBean doesn't contains the properties id,name they exist in User entity.
please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [`<ui:repeat>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/ui/repeat.html) is an UI component while [`<f:selectItem>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/f/selectitem) is a taghandler (like JSTL). Taghandlers runs during view build time before UI components which runs during view render time. So at the moment the `<ui:repeat>` runs, there is no means of a `<f:selectItem>`.

A `<c:forEach>`, which is also a tag handler, would work, but much better is to use [`<f:selectItems>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/f/selectitems) instead. Since JSF 2.0 it can take a collection and support the `var` attribute as well:

```xml
<ice:selectOneMenu id="users">
    <f:selectItems value="#{user.usersList}" var="userItem" 
        itemLabel="#{userItem.name}" itemValue="#{userItem.id}" />
</ice:selectOneMenu>
```

Note that the `var` attribute should not clash with an existing bean in the scope.

#### See also:

- [`selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)
- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: it gives me an exception, that the property name doesn't exist in UserBean !!!!!!!! why it thinks that the list is of type UserBean not User ??????

Comment: Can you please tone a bit down? I gather that you're talking about a `PropertyNotFoundException` on `usersList`? Well, then that means that you don't have a `public List<User> getUsersList()` method in the backing bean class represented by the `#{user}` managed bean.

Comment: Oh, you are not using JSF managed beans, but you are using Spring managed beans (you didn't tell/tag anything about this in your question, so I couldn't forsee it). Well, then use `#{user.getUsersList()}` if standard EL call is not possible (I don't use Spring, so I can't tell if this is indeed true). You have by the way a syntax error in your class; `Public` is an invalid keyword, it should be `public`.

Comment: even when using #{user.getUsersList()} i keep getting same error.

Comment: ah found it, the var name in loop was matching the ManagedBean name: @Component("user") , it was fixed by changing the var name.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That would conflict. I updated the answer to reflect that as well.

Comment: any ideas how to get the Selected Users in such case ?

Comment: This is offtopic. Ask a new question. Hint: `<ice:selectOneMenu value>`.

Answer (score 4):

why not use f:selectItems. I think something like this would work.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{user.getUsersList()}" var="user" itemLabel="#{user.name}"
                                            itemValue="#{user.id}" />
```

**EDIT** 
 also try removing the brackets from the user.getUsersList() in your code , i think its not how you call a function in jsf2

Comment: As per your edit, this is valid in EL 2.2, but plain clumsy if it's just a simple getter.