# Setting <f:param> value with <ui:repeat> var

Tags: jsf, uirepeat

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{sampleManagedBean.food}" var="food">
        <h:commandLink value="Name" action="#{sampleManagedBean.outcome}">
            <f:param name="name" value="ssd" />
            <f:param name="v" value="#{food.boy}" />
        </h:commandLink>
        <h2>#{food.boy}</h2>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

I can't get the the second `<f:param>` value which is set based on `<ui:repeat var>`. I can get only the first one which is hardcoded.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8759384/617373

Comment: I looked at the BaluC post about the rules of UI components and have changed the scope but i don't understand what is the other thing.We declare the list in the constructor?How do you preserve the list state while submitting?

Answer (score 0):

The `ui:repeat` is an UI component while `f:param` is a taghandler (like JSTL). Taghandlers run during view build time before UI components which run during view render time
([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152322/uirepeat-doesnt-work-with-fselectitem)).

In our case it means that in the view build phase `f:param` knows nothing about `#{food.boy}`. `c:forEach` will be fine, but if we call some kind of ajax action to change the size of
`#{sampleManagedBean.food}` and rerender the form, we'll not see any changes on page. Because partial rerendering (ajax) affects only UI component tree. `c:forEach` is somewhere between hardcoding and `ui:repeat`, we'll have to reload the page to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this way,

```
    <h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{sampleManagedBean.food}" var="food">
        <h:commandLink value="Name" action="#{sampleManagedBean.outcome}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="ssd" target="#{sampleManagedBean.name}" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{food.boy}" target="#{sampleManagedBean.v}" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </ui:repeat>
    </h:form>
```